# What is the meaning for Design Specification in documentation of a project?

Tags: documentation

Can anybody help me to understand what is the meaning to design specification in the documentation of a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of software, Design Specification is usually a design document that describes all data, architectural, interface and component-level design for the software.

A design specification provides explicit information about the requirements for a product and how the product is to be put together. Its use is called for where a product has to be specially made to meet a unique need. For example, a design specification must include all necessary information that I've listed above i.e. data, architectural, interface and component-level design for the software not excluding the documentation.

An example can be found [Here](http://www.bradapp.com/docs/sdd.html)

Comment: Frankline, can you help me in praperation of Design Specification for and android application (initially based on login screen ,via multilevel security,and profile page).

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal There is typos, it should be preparation not praperation.

Comment: @Frankline, in your opinion who is responsible for writing design specification? Architect ?